# get current frame from an one row graphic

Tags: java, android

I need to get the current frame of a image but it does not work and I don't know why...
[image]
Could someone help me pls... thx

```
package com.android.testgame;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class Bomb
{
    private final Bitmap bmp;

    private final int width;

    private final int height;

    private int currentFrame = 0;

    private static final int BMPROWS = 1;

    private static final int BMPCOLUMNS = 13;

    private int x = 0;

    private int y = 0;

    public Bomb(GameView gameView, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        this.width = bmp.getWidth() / BMPCOLUMNS;
        this.height = bmp.getHeight() / BMPROWS;
        this.bmp = bmp;
        x = 250;
        y = 250;
    }

    private void update()
    {
        currentFrame = GameLoopThread.getCurrbombfr();
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        update();

        int srcX = currentFrame * width;

        int srcY = height;

        Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);

        Rect dst = new Rect(x, y, x + width, y + height);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? The code seems right for me. The only part I can blame that may be wrong is `GameLoopThread.getCurrbombfr();`.

Comment: it does not show anything

Comment: @GustavoMaciel if i change canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null); to canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, null, dst, null); then i get a distorted image

Comment: the `src` parameter tells the canvas which part of your spritesheet you want to draw. If you pass null, you're saying to it that you want the whole image (all frames) to be drawn. Is this what you really want to do?

Comment: @GustavoMaciel I want just the current frame but it does not display it when I add the src parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

int srcY = height;

To:

int srcY = 0;

EDIT (explanation):

If you look at the definition of the source rectangle:

Rect src = new Rect(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);

You are drawing from srcY to srcY + height. However you just set srcY = height, therefore you are attempting to draw from height to height+height. Settings srcY to 0 then changes the draw area from 0 to 0+height which is what you actually want. You're not seeing anything because drawing height to height+height is obviously out of the image bounds.

Comment: You could improve this answer significantly by adding an explanation about why this solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Comment: @Brian DeWolff Thx you very much for your explanation...